# change null hypothesis in lmtest in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

I have a linear model generated using `lm`. I use the `coeftest` function in the package `lmtest` go test a hypothesis with my desired `vcov` from the `sandwich` package. The default null hypothesis is `beta = 0`. What if I want to test `beta = 1`, for example. I know I can simply take the estimated coefficient, subtract 1 and divide by the provided standard error to get the t-stat for my hypothesis. However, there must be functionality for this already in R. What is the right way to do this?

MWE:

```
require(lmtest)
require(sandwich)
set.seed(123)
x = 1:10
y = x + rnorm(10)
mdl = lm(y ~ x)
z = coeftest(mdl, df=Inf, vcov=NeweyWest)
b = z[2,1]
se = z[2,2]
mytstat = (b-1)/se
print(mytstat)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the formally correct way to do this:

```
require(multcomp)
zed = glht(model=mdl, linfct=matrix(c(0,1), nrow=1, ncol=2), rhs=1, alternative="two.sided", vcov.=NeweyWest)
summary(zed)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an offset of -1*x

```
mdl<-lm(y~x)
mdl2 <- lm(y ~ x-offset(x) )

> mdl

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
     0.5255       0.9180  

> mdl2

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x - offset(x))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
    0.52547     -0.08197
```

You can look at `summary(mdl2)` to see the p-value (and it is the same as in `mdl`.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi  I didn’t test. I was trying to subtract x from every y value so that a flat line would be the Null hypothesis when the “observed” slope was 1

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no default function to test the model coefficients against arbitrary value (`1` in your case). There is the `offset` trick presented in the other answer, but it's not that straightforward (and always be careful with such model modifications). So, your expression `(b-1)/se` is actually [a good way to do it](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/29991/5509).

I have two notes on your code:

1. You can use `summary(mdl)` to get the t-test for 0.
2. You are using `lmtest` with covariance structure (which will change the t-test values), but your original `lm` model doesn't have it. Perhaps this could be a problem? Perhaps you should use `glm` and specify the correlation structure from the start.